# Need to change the html of button name based on selected variant

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I have created a condition to disable the add to cart button if there is inventory available in Shopify. I have the button working, but the i want to change the message to 'sold out' rathert than 'add to cart/ and disabled.

Here is the code i have put togther so far, the selectedVariant function which is being passed into the validate function is not shown here, but is working at getting the active variant.

```
let addToCartFormSelector = '#add-to-cart-form'

let productForm = {
validate: function(event, selectedVariant) {

let
  $form = $(this),
  hasVariant = selectedVariant !== null,
  canAddToCart = hasVariant && selectedVariant.inventory_quantity > 0,

        // Select a valid variant if available
        if (canAddToCart) {
          // Available, enable the submit button, change text, show quantity elements
          $id.val(selectedVariant.id);
          $("#spanid").html("Add to cart");
          $addToCartButton.prop('disabled', false)
        }
        else {
          // Sold out, disable the submit button, change text, hide quantity elements
          $id.val('');
          $("#spanid").html("Sold out");
          $addToCartButton.prop('disabled', true)
        }
      }
    }

init: function() {
  $(document).on('form:change', addToCartFormSelector, productForm.validate);
}
```

here is the html markup

```
{% form 'product', id: "add-to-cart-form" %}

        <button
          id="add-to-cart-button"
          type="submit"
          name="add"
          class="btn btn-main mx-auto w-100 js-cart-link"
          {% if can_add_to_cart != true %}disabled{% endif %}>
          <span id="spanid">
              {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
          </span>
        </button>

{% endform %}
```

Comment: I think you need to check the `variantchange` callback into default `option_selection.js` from the Shopify side, it will help you check the selected variant and perform an action according to variant data.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample code from the Shopify default core theme called `Brooklyn` and here how they implement the same function called `variantChange`.

I think it will give you an insight into further action.

[image]

This is the code snippet, for your reference from the same `Brooklyn` theme, you need to check the theme you are using and utilized the current code.
[image]